# javascript json request with some parameters

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, get

So a simple question:

JavaScript needs to send to server that request:

> myserver/scipt.php?LANG=EN&AGENT={"Login":{"name":"user","pass":"user"}}

How I need to form url and data in Ajax?

Is this right?

```
var formData = {
            "login":$("#field1").val(),
            "pass":$("#field2").val()
               };

$.ajax({
    url:'http://myserver/scipt.php?LANG=EN&',
    type:'GET',
    data:'AGENT=' + $.toJSON(formData),
    success: function(res) {
                        alert(res);
                           }
      });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend sending JSON via POST instead of GET. GET has some limitations that you want to avoid.

A part from that, yes, your code seems ok.

EDIT:

Sorry, your code is not ok.

Change the data line to:

```
data: $.toJSON(formData),
```

Comment: GET has some length limitations (not all browsers/servers accept the same amount of data sent via GET, but there is a limit).

Comment: There is no sign that the data would even approach the length limitations of GET requests that browsers impose.

Comment: @Quentin you can't say that. Especially if data is generated by user.

Comment: The data consists of a username and password; between the two of them, they aren't likely to beat the two THOUSAND plus characters you need to overflow a URL length. If you are going to reject GET on the basis of "users might type in lots of data", then you will end up banning GET for every form with free text input.

Comment: If we assume that only those 2 fields are sent, then yes, you're right. Anyways, why making it crash-prone when he could just change to POST and avoid all that? +Sending JSON via GET just doesn't look ok.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL encode any strings you want to pass through Ajax.

If jQuery works anything like a normal form, you also need to put all your query string data into `data` to avoid the existing query string being destroyed.

```
url:'http://myserver/scipt.php',
type:'GET',
data: { 
    "AGENT": $.toJSON(formData),
    "LANG": "EN"
},
```

Note, you should use POST requests if you are transmitting user credentials. You don't want them cached or stored in server access.log files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the **data** to the server in the form of a map ..

Your data is already in json format.. You need not do `$.toJSON` again

Instead of

```
data:'AGENT=' + $.toJSON(formData),
```

send it this way

```
 data:{ 'AGENT' : {'Login' : formData } },
```

Comment: That will send `AGENT[Login][user]=foo&AGENT[Login][pass]=bar`, which isn't what was requested.